# How to disable attribute menu item after it is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, express

I can click on the Photos menu 4 times quickly, and the "$.get(..." is sent to the server 4 times.
I need to disable this menu (after it is clicked once) so it can not be clicked on again.
Environment: NodeJS, Express, Pug, Jquery
Thanks,
Pat

```
--------------DOM----------------------------------
// file = photos.pug
div#wrapper2
    div#altnav
      ul
        include includes/altnav.pug
        include includes/navjs.pug
---------------------------------------------------
// file = includes/altnav.pug
li: a.navigation(href='#', data-level='/images/cs/Photos') Photos
---------------------------------------------------
// file = includes/navjs.pug
script.
    $(function(){ // jQuery DOM ready
        $('.navigation').click(function () {
            var level = 'm' + $(this).data('level');        // Append an 'm' so I know this came from navjs.pug
            var url = '/navigation?level=' + escape(level); // Send this to the /router/photos.js
            $.get(url, function (data) { 
                $('body').html(data);           // data = new HTML page to be loaded by browser
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){ // jQuery DOM ready
   $('.navigation').click(function () {
      $(this).css({
        "pointer-events": "none",
        "cursor": "default"
      });
          /* then your code */
   });
});
```

Comment: Glad I helped :)

Comment: How can I disable all menu items, once one of them is clicked?

Comment: if they are siblings `$(this).siblings().css(...)`

Comment: They are siblings, but $(this).siblings().css(...) did not disable any of the menus, even the one I clicked on.

Comment: I'll write up a new Question for this situation.

Comment: my apologies, siblings() won't work because your a tag are inside li tags which means they have no siblings. you should try to use event delegation on the outsider ul. i'll find your new question and post the appropriate answer

Answer (score 0):

I normally add a flag for this to clicked element like this

```
$('.navigation').on('click',function(){
    if(!$(this).data('clicked')){
         $(this).data('clicked',true);
         // do rest of your staff
    }
});
```

Or if you want to disabled it if its a form element you can use :

```
$('.navigation').on('click',function(){ 
     // do rest of your staff
     $(this).prop( "disabled", true );
});
```

or if you want to block pointer interaction use CSS. `pointer-events: none;` you can use :

```
$('.navigation').on('click',function(){ 
     // do rest of your staff
     $(this).css( "pointer-events", 'none' );
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I add this flag. rel=#selector or alt=#selector or rel=selector, or alt=selector,  or something else.

Comment: by `#selector` i mean your element you want to bind on click to.. in your case you should overwrite it with `$('.navigation')` .. i will update the answer for better understanding.